# Java decimal/ascii and base converting

Tags: java, perl, hex

I'm converting code from perl to java.  I'm sort of stuck on finding the equivalents in java.

Here's my Perl code:

```
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($hex_); $i = $i + 2)
    {
      $ascii = $ascii.chr(hexdec(substr($hex_, $i, 2))); 
    }
```

so in java i can do hex.substring(i,2).  I got that part.

How would I do the chr and hexdec part in Java?

Here's what I have so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for you to go about parsing hexadecimal numbers manually, you can just use [Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). Similarily, there is an [Integer.toString(int i, int radix)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29) which will convert your integer to a String with the desired base.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually extremely surprised you didn't use `pack` for your Perl version!

```
$ascii = pack 'H*', $hex_;
```

Anyway, the Java port of your Perl code, if you want to code it manually (as opposed to using something like [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/)) is:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i + 1 < hex.length(); i += 2)
    sb.append((char) Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(i, i + 2)));
String ascii = sb.toString();
```